# Using HTML In Trello Cards

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I'm using Zapier to forward Gmail emails to make new Trello cards as they come in under a specific label. The emails are HTML emails and when Zapier creates a new card in Trello I see all the HTML tags.

Is there a way to enable HTML in Trello cards?

Comment: Where are you seeing the HTML tags?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is what it looks like when the new card is created.  - <html> <head> <title>New</title> </head> <body> <p><strong>testing</strong></p> <p>test1<br /> test2<br /> test43<br /> test4</p> <br> <p><strong>Instructions</strong></p>

Comment: This is in the card title, or the card description?

Comment: It's in the card description sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trello uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) in its description, not HTML.

However, there are online tools that convert from one to the other, such as [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try).  I don't think Zapier has any content conversion utilities, so you might have to do this manually after the card is created.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get his working. This may be useful to somebody else with a similar issue. I was able to use nl2br() function on my message data which put in the breaks where I needed them I ended up just using plain text and using a function I found on http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php which converts the breaks. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, can you explain how you use this function? Does Zapier call the function before passing to trello?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do that to synchronise a simple HTML webpage exported in excel with a trello board.

1. use a [macro](http://antilope2005.free.fr/index.php/divers/supprimer-le-code-html-dune-cellule-excel/?unapproved=33452&moderation-hash=1ea97bd88580e1727e5ba809d6fdec12#comment-33452) in excel to convert the html
2. Push your table in google sheets
3. Use [zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations/trello/11712/update-rows-on-google-sheets-whenever-a-trello-card-is-moved-to-a-list) or automate.io or integromat to syncrhonize Google sheets with trello (create or modify a card whan new or updated row)